# not able to extract attribute from xml in groovy script

Tags: groovy, automation

I am trying to automate using groovy script. Here is my script. I am not able to mention namspace.

```html
<ns2:contactPref xmlns="namespace 1" xmlns:ns2="name space 2">
  <ns2:Information>
    <value>Pass</value>
    </ns2:Information>
  <ns2:contactPreference>
    <ns2:contactPointRel>
      <contactPoint xs:type="Tele" xmlns:xs="namespace 3">
        <cat>mob</cat>
        <med>Int</med>
        </contactPoint>
      </ns2:contactPointRel>
      </ns2:contactPreference>
  </ns2:contactPref>
```

Now I want to fetch attribute at contactPoint tag
for this I have tried like this

```
groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.Groovyutills(context)
def xPath=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
def type=context.expand('${GetResponse#Response#//*:contactPoint/@xs:type}')
log.info type
```

tried this

```
def type=context.expand('${GetResponse#Response#//*:contactPoint/@type}')
```

and I also tried this

```
def resp=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetResponse#Response")
def type1=(String)xPath.evaluate('//:contactpoint/@xs:type',resp,xPathConstants.STRING)
```

but no help. please some one tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this it should work

> @{namespace 3}type

if you see **xs:type="Tele" xmlns:xs="namespace 3"** in **contactPoint** then xs which has value **namespace 3** and {type} is Tele

Edited - You could use something like this - with xmlString as XML

> def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
>   println
>   xml.contactPreference.contactPointRel.contactPoint."@{namespace
>   3}type"

Comment: Thanks can u tell me which method should i try this one?means xpath.evaluate or context.expnad?

Comment: Hi, I tried for both like `context.expand('${GetResponse#Response#//*:contactPoint/@{namespace 3}type}' )` for this it is printing the line as it is. and for `(String)xPath.evaluate('//:contactpoint/@{namespace 3}type',resp,xPathConstants.STRING )` showing error

Comment: I have edited answer to add the code which works. Please try

Comment: Hi,xmlSlurper goes in kind of infinite loop.. notable to check anything. why?

Comment: Sorry,won't be able to paste full code. Can u please suggest possible problem cause when I tried with small XML response even Slurper behaved sluggish